# I have NDVI layer in Earth Engine. I want to assign and calculate area of good and bad ndvi area

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google

```
    var mergedCollection = s2.map(function(image) {
    return image.select(['B8', 'B4'], ['NIR', 'red'])
    })


   var mergedAllFunction = function(image) {
   var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'red']).rename('NDVI');


   var thres1 = ndvi.gte(0).rename('thres1')
   var thres2=ndvi.gt(0.1) && ndvi.lt(0.3).rename('thres2')
   var thres3=ndvi.gt(0.4) && ndvi.lt(0.7).rename('thres3')
   var thres4=ndvi.gt(0.8) && ndvi.lte(1).rename('thres4')

   return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(thres1,thres2,thres3,thres4);
   print(ndvi)
   }
```

How do I get area (count of pixels under each threshold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems in your code.  First, using `&&` in that way will not work for reasons described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server#conditionals).  Second, you can't `addBands(arg1, arg2,...)`.  Those args should be in a list.  Here's a complete example that incorporates your code and a previous answer:

```
var mergedCollection = s2
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-03-01')
    .map(function(image) {
      return image.select(['B8', 'B4'], ['NIR', 'red'])
    })

var mergedAllFunction = function(image) {
 var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'red']).rename('NDVI');

 var thres1 = ndvi.gte(0).rename('thres1')
 var thres2=ndvi.gt(0.1).and(ndvi.lt(0.3)).rename('thres2')
 var thres3=ndvi.gt(0.4).and(ndvi.lt(0.7)).rename('thres3')
 var thres4=ndvi.gt(0.8).and(ndvi.lte(1)).rename('thres4')

 return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands([thres1,thres2,thres3,thres4]);
}

var median = mergedCollection.median();

var merged = mergedAllFunction(median);

var areas = merged
    .select(['thres1', 'thres2', 'thres3', 'thres4'])
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: geometry,  // a geometry
      scale: 10,   // scale = 10 for sentinel-2 'red' band
      maxPixels: 1e9  
    });
print(areas)
```

Comment: I tried this same code in Python API of Earth engine. It is showing the following error:EEException: Invalid argument for ee.Reducer(): ({'geometry': [[74.022029, 20.103245], [74.022029, 20.116564], [74.038048, 20.116564], [74.038048, 20.103245]], 'reducer': <ee.Reducer object at 0x03D06FF0>, 'scale': 10},).  Must be a ComputedObject. ...  Can you help me with this error.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate a dictionary of the summed area inside the per image function:

```
var areaThres1 = thres1.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: YOURAREAOFINTEREST,  // a geometry
    scale: 10,   // scale = 10 for sentinel-2 'red' band
    maxPixels: 1e9  
  });
```

Return the value as a property to each image:

```
return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(thres1).addBands(thres2).addBands(thres3).addBands(thres4).set('area_sqm_th1', areaThres1);
```

Comment: I did not understand the per image function. Can you write a sample code in earth engine platform and share the link . Thanks for your help

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1f814dbf8e9c1ccfea20f05e38fc4c7

Comment: Hi Kuik,thanks for prompt reply. I used your code bt I need the area calculated(according to threshold) to be printed in console. But when i use print option for the variable areathresh1. It is giving error.Please help in this regard

Comment: I am getting this error: umber (Error)
Failed to decode JSON.
Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is missing or null.
Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.

Comment: You cannot print inside a mapped "server-side" function. Read the help pages to find out about that. use mergedAllFunction.first().get('area_sqm_th1') outside the mapped function.